# Questions about the sed command to remove the characters and create a new file

Tags: linux, database, bash, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file called "Jimbleprot.pep" and It looks like this:

```
  119 >TRINITY_DN10025_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN10025_c0_g1_i1::g.7937::m.7937 TRINITY_DN10025_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN10025_c0_g1_i1::g.7937  ORF type:5prime_partial len:201 (-),score=29.41 TRINITY_DN10025_c0_g1_i1:192-794(-)
  120DEDDEPQELQVHVDVSLPGTPLGSENSVHSGCSHKSNVSSSLVAA
  123 TPTCVRLEEELHGPIRDGLS*
  124 >TRINITY_DN10026_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN10026_c0_g1_i1::g.7944::m.7944 TRINITY_DN10026_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN10026_c0_g1_i1::g.7944  ORF type:internal len:115 (+),score=15.25,NACHT|PF05729.12|0.068,Tti2|PF10521.9|0.1      4 TRINITY_DN10026_c0_g1_i1:2-343(+)
  125 SVEDLAIKILTTCGIPAPSVGEKEKLQELLKIVTRKCLLILDNLDHAFHADDKRRDSMDK
  126 SIRTTYKPSFSGNSTASSNISESSAAAFASSSANLPGIPTSISFAPYRSGIVHS
  127 >TRINITY_DN10028_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN10028_c0_g1_i1::g.7938::m.7938 TRINITY_DN10028_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN10028_c0_g1_i1::g.7938  ORF type:5prime_partial len:223 (-),score=32.40,gi|114149223|sp|Q9NUQ8.2|ABCF3_HUMA      N|66.97|6e-103,gi|114149223|sp|Q9NUQ8.2|ABCF3_HUMAN|23.39|7e-11,ABC_tran|PF00005.27|3.4e-23,AAA_21|PF13304.6|0.00057,AAA_21|PF13304.6|3.2e-05,SMC_N|PF02463.19|0.082,SMC_N|PF02463.19|6.7e-05,AAA_22|PF13401.      6|0.00019,AAA_30|PF13604.6|0.00038,AAA_16|PF13191.6|0.0019,AAA_29|PF13555.6|0.0081,NACHT|PF05729.12|0.0075,AAA_15|PF13175.6|0.015,AAA_15|PF13175.6|1.1e+03,Pox_A32|PF04665.12|0.01,Dynamin_N|PF00350.23|0.016      ,MobB|PF03205.14|0.026,DUF87|PF01935.17|0.039,DUF87|PF01935.17|3.3e+03,AAA_23|PF13476.6|0.033,AAA_24|PF13479.6|0.2,AAA_24|PF13479.6|1.1e+03,FtsK_SpoIIIE|PF01580.18|0.069,AAA_18|PF13238.6|0.079,AAA_18|PF132      38.6|3e+03,DLIC|PF05783.11|0.046,T2SSE|PF00437.20|0.063,SbcCD_C|PF13558.6|0.33,MMR_HSR1|PF01926.23|0.059,TniB|PF05621.11|36,TniB|PF05621.11|3.7,Arf|PF00025.21|0.27,Arf|PF00025.21|2.2e+03,AAA_19|PF13245.6|0      .18,TsaE|PF02367.17|0.23,Roc|PF08477.13|0.22 TRINITY_DN10028_c0_g1_i1:59-727(-)
  128IAVVGDNGSGKTTLLKILLGELEPVKLATKFPGKNVEHYRHQLG
RYGVSGDLATRFQGGVILVSHDERLVRSMCDEVWVCGNRQVKSIEGGFDQYKRMVQEELQAVLQ*
  132 >TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1_i1::g.2343::m.2343 TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1_i1::g.2343  ORF type:5prime_partial len:174 (+),score=44.19,EF-hand_7|PF13499.6|0.15,EF-hand_6|PF13      405.6|1.2,EF-hand_6|PF13405.6|8.8e+02,EF-hand_6|PF13405.6|6e+03,EF-hand_6|PF13405.6|1.3e+03,EF-hand_1|PF00036.32|0.16,EF-hand_1|PF00036.32|5.8e+03,EF-hand_1|PF00036.32|6.3e+03,EF-hand_1|PF00036.32|8.6e+03       TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1_i1:2-523(+)
  133 EQHPKIRMQIAQKVFNVLDPDKKGYANKDDIMALTVDKLKAIADIVDPDYANTEEYEHVL
  134 FGEAEVRDAFQDALEEGNGELHLQKLIQKYKDLGGSEKVARELFAMLKPKSKDKATADEV
  135 EENLSNVLELYKKIRDEDKSGIFYDRHLQEDKEIMAKTLHEKTDTDGTKHDEL*
  136 >TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1_i2::g.2344::m.2344 TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1_i2::g.2344  ORF type:5prime_partial len:174 (+),score=54.09,EF-hand_7|PF13499.6|0.13,EF-hand_8|PF13      833.6|1.6,EF-hand_8|PF13405.6|1.2,EF-hand_6|PF13405.6|1.5e+03,EF-hand_6|PF13405.6|6e+03,EF-hand_6|PF13405.6|8.8e+02,EF-hand_1|PF00036.32|0.16,EF-hand _1|PF00036.32|PF00036.32|6.7e+03 TRINITY_DN1002_c0_g1_i2:2-523(+)
  137 EQHPKIRMQIAQKVFNVLDPDKKGYANKDDIMALTVDKLKAIADIVDPDYANTEEYEHVL
  138 FGEEEVRDAFQDALEEGNGELHLQKLILKYKDLGGSEKVARELFAMLKPKSKDKATADEV
  139 EENLSNVLELYKKIRDDDKSGVFYDRHLQEDKEIMAKTLDEGTNTDGAKHEEL*
```

and this file is about more than 8000 lines , I want to use the `sed` command to remove the `*` in the first 5000 line and output the result to a new file called "newprot.fasta". I think I may need the `|` to `head`but I'm not sure how to do it and use them in the `sed` command. Thank you!

Comment: Should all lines be output or only the first 5000 lines?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @only the first 5000 lines with `*`removed.

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is, as is usually the case when you're working with a file instead of a stream that's part of a pipeline, a better choice than `sed` here:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '1,5000 g/\*/s/\*//g' '1,5000 w newprot.fasta' Q | ed -s Jimbleprot.pep
```

will remove every `*` character in the first 5000 lines of the file, and then save those first 5000 lines in the new file.

Can also be written with `ed`'s input as a heredoc instead if you prefer it for readability:

```sh
ed -s Jimbleprot.pep <<EOF
1,5000 g/\*/s/\*//g
1,5000 w newprot.fasta
Q
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

My way is to divide it to 3 parts (maybe there is better way):

1. take only the first 5000 lines in new file and delete the `*`.

   ```
   sed '5001,$ d' Jimbleprot.pep | tr -d '*' > temp_file.txt
   ```
2. save only the last 3000+- raws in the `Jimbleprot.pep` file:

   ```
   tail -n +5001 Jimbleprot.pep > test.tmp && mv test.tmp Jimbleprot.pep
   ```
3. Unify all files to the `newprot.fasta`:

   ```
   cat temp_file.txt Jimbleprot.pep > newprot.fasta
   ```

It should work, again i don't know if it's the best way but it's my way.

**Edit:**
if you want only the first 5000 lines without the `*` just do step 1.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1,5000s/\*//g;w newprot.fasta' Jimbleprot.pep
```

This will alter the first 5000 lines removing any `*`'s and the write every line to `newprot.fasta`.

If only the first 5000 line are required in `newprot.fasta`, use:

```
sed -e '1,5000s/\*//g;w newprot.fasta' -e '5000q' Jimbleprot.pep
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also work

`head -n 5000 Jimbleprot.pep | sed 's/\*//g' > newprot.fasta`